# Math functions for geometry_msgs?

Tags: geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
What is the best practice for doing simple math operations such as 'calculating 3D euclidian distance between two geometry_msgs::Points'?

I found a Linearmath folder in the 'tf' include for vectors, but did not find any related documentation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61957/math-functions-for-geometry_msgs?/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it is really simple (like your example): Do it by hand, i.e. hypot(p1.x - p2.x,...).

If it is a little more advanced, or you might do more than 1 simple calculation: Convert the messages (which are just 'dumb' containers for data) to their respective tf data types. There are conversion functions like tf::pointMsgToTF for converting forth and back. The tf data types have all the geometry operations you'd expect for linear math.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-05-02**:
Also note that the [geometry stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry) includes nice functions for getting `tf` data into `Eigen` and `KDL` types.  This can be useful if you need more complex math operations.